# Why I'm getting Promise { <pending> }?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JavaScript and asynchronous functions. I'm trying to find some items by Id on my repository.

This is how I'm doing the call:

```
const foundedSectionsList = sections.map(async (sectionId) => {
 return await sectionsRepository.getSectionById(sectionId)
})

console.log(foundedSectionsList)
```

And that is my result:

```
[
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]
```

Why this is happening? I did use async on the map function and also I'm awaiting for the repository to respond.

I tried to change the position of the async and await.

Comment: `foundedSectionsList` is an array of pending promises. To use the results you will need to await the array, like with `Promise.all`.

Comment: Note if you use `Promise.all` there's no real need for your `map` to be `async` or for you to `await` the async call. `map` will return an array of promises, and `await Promise.all(arr)` will `await` them to resolve (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting promises in the array because when you are calling these asynchronous functions they don't wait for result to come in when you are passing them inside map. Map will simply run without waiting for previous function call.

Also this is not a right approach to call asynchronous functions inside **map**. The right approach would be to use Promise.all.

The Promise.all() method returns a single promise that resolves when all the input promises have been resolved. The returned promise resolves to an array of the results of the input promises

```js
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('The first promise has resolved');
    resolve(10);
  }, 1 * 1000);
});
const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('The second promise has resolved');
    resolve(20);
  }, 2 * 1000);
});
const p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('The third promise has resolved');
    resolve(30);
  }, 3 * 1000);
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then((results) => {
  const total = results.reduce((p, c) => p + c);

  console.log(`Results: ${results}`);
  console.log(`Total: ${total}`);
});
```

The output will look like this:

```
The first promise has resolved 
The second promise has resolved 
The third promise has resolved 
Results: 10,20,30 Total: 60
```

When all promises have resolved, the values from these promises are passed into the callback of the then() method as an array. After that results will be returned.

Just to put it all together the Promise.all() method accepts a list of promises and returns a new promsie that resolve to an array of results of the input promises if all the input promises resolved; or reject with an error of the first rejected

You should use the Promise.all() method to aggregate results from multiple asynchronous operations.

I hope it clears your query. Cheers bud! :)